# What does the return parameter "flags" mean in ReadMsgUDP?

Tags: go, udp

I'm using the function `ReadMsgUDP` in connectionless-oriented UDP, and it goes well so far. But I have no idea about the return parameter `flags`, anyone knows it?

Moreover, I'm Chinese and cannot visit the official Go website in Google, can anyone send me some official documents of Go via mail?

Comment: Thanks to icza and my colleague, flags means things like MSG_DONTROUTE, MSG_EOR, MSG_TRUNC,etc, in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to have access to Go's website to read the documentation. The distributions include a tool called [`godoc`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc) which can start a local HTTP server and host a similar website you see on Go's home page. You can start it locally by running the following command:

```
godoc -http=:6060
```

Then visit the following local URL in your browser:

```
http://localhost:6060/
```

Documentation of [`UDPConn.ReadMsgUDP()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#UDPConn.ReadMsgUDP):

```
http://localhost:6060/pkg/net/#UDPConn.ReadMsgUDP
```

Quoting the relevant part:

```
func (c *UDPConn) ReadMsgUDP(b, oob []byte) (n, oobn, flags int, addr *UDPAddr, err error)
```

> ReadMsgUDP reads a packet from c, copying the payload into b and the associated out-of-band data into oob. It returns the number of bytes copied into b, the number of bytes copied into oob, **the flags that were set on the packet and the source address of the packet**.

Comment: Thank you very much! Though godoc also needs to have access to Go's website, I copied it from my colleague. And it works now!

Comment: @TheHan Pages presented by `godoc` may include content from the official Go home page, but if you don't have access, those content will simply not be displayed. It works without internet connection (or having no connection to Go's home page).

Comment: Content from sites such as github, golang-china,etc, will help a lot. I will try vpn to visit google when these sites have no information I want afterwards.